# Android Studio SQLite dont insert data into database if data already exists

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I was reading this post ([Android Studio Sqlite don't insert in database if value already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261406/android-studio-sqlite-dont-insert-in-database-if-value-already-exists)) because I have the same exact question. I followed and copied the steps of *Phan Van Linh* but I arrived to an error of `nullPointerException`

Somewhere in my **DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public Boolean verifyData(String TABLE_NAME, String id){
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + id + " = ?";
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery(query, null);         <------------ LINE 42
    if (res.moveToFirst()){
        res.close();
        return true;
    }

    res.close();
    return false;

}
public long insertData(String name,String surname,String id){
    if (verifyData(TABLE_NAME, id)){            <------------ LINE 53
        return 0;
    }

    // set the format to sql date time
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    Date time = new Date();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1, dateFormat.format(date));
    contentValues.put(COL_2, timeFormat.format(time));
    contentValues.put(COL_3, name);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, surname);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, id);
    long result=db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    return result;

}
```

Somewhere in my **MainActivity.java**

```
public void AutoAdd(){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd 'at' HH:mm:ss");
        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

LINE 329 ------> long isInserted = myDb.insertData(theName.getText().toString(), theSur.getText().toString(), theId.getText().toString());

    }
```

**Logcat**

```
2021-04-10 09:24:17.889 16707-16707/com.example.AppDraft3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.AppDraft3, PID: 16707
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.AppDraft3/com.example.AppDraft3.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3654)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3806)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
        at com.example.AppDraft3.DatabaseHelper.verifyData(DatabaseHelper.java:42)
        at com.example.AppDraft3.DatabaseHelper.insertData(DatabaseHelper.java:53)
        at com.example.AppDraft3.MainActivity.AutoAdd(MainActivity.java:329)
        at com.example.AppDraft3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:86)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7963)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7952)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3629)
```

Comment: Before calling insertData() you must already have opened your database, your variable db can't be null. Also post the logcat or sometthing "ERROR HEREEEEEEE" doesn't tell us anything

Comment: Sorry my bad, added the logcat sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a line that instantiates the variable/object **db** e.g. :-

```
public Boolean verifyData(String TABLE_NAME, String id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + id + " = ''";
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery(query, null);         <------------ ERROR HEREEEEEEE
    if (res.moveToFirst()){
        res.close();
        return true;
    }
    res.close();
    return false;
}
```

However, the `verifyData` Method is trying to extract records where the passed id = '' so will always return false.

I believe that you should therefore additionally change

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + id + " = ''";
```

to :-

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE id = '" + id + "'";
```

If the **id** column were defined as being **UNIQUE** (which it probably should be) then as the convenience **[insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))** methods uses the equivalent of `INSERT OR IGNORE` it would ignore the duplicate id and return a value of -1 without inserting a row (and thus the verifyData method wouldn't be required)

Comment: Adding writeableDatabase removes the error but it still adds an entry even though it has a duplicate

Comment: @MRPenguin although the issue, the null pointer exception, has been resolved. I have amended the answer to remedy your next issue you have encountered. Please note that subsequent issues should result in subsequent questions.

Comment: Sir, thank you very much!! even though my post is a duplicate I'm really glad you still answered especially my subsequent question. You just saved me and my group!!  ☜(ˆ▿ˆc)